# uncaught referenceError: sKey is not defined onkeydown in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, keycode

I am having a hard time with this script... I have a html form name="mainF" that has two input->submit inside the form.. The first submit is in a navigation that has a position of fixed that floats on top of the page and every page through mvc.  When I instantiate my app on the public directory (index.php) i also include a header.php on top of $app = new App; and footer.php on the bottom.  In my header.php page i have my css, javascript and start the body plus the start of a html form markup and a navigation for search.  In the footer.php i have the close of form html markup < / form >. When I am in the login's page (through my views in the middle of header.php and footer.php) there would be two submit input on the page.  I am working on this script to detect the input->text for each section of input->submit on the page so if I put in a keyword for the search section I could press my enter key on the keyboard and it will execute input->submit for search, or if I attempt to login and type the username and the password I could press enter on my keyboard right after I type and It attempts to log me in.  This script works in IE but not in Chrome and it gives me an error code in the console of chrome: uncaught referenceError: sKey is not defined onkeydown... and the same for logKey: uncaught referenceError: logKey is not defined onkeydown...  Please Help!

This script is in the footers.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchBTN').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#skeys').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#searchBTN').prop('disabled', false);
            function sKey(event) {
                var s = event.keyCode;
                if(s == 13) {
                    document.mainF.searchBtn.click();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#loginB').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#pass').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('#loginB').prop('disabled', false);
            function logKey(event) {
                var l = event.keyCode;
                if(l == 13) {
                    document.mainF.loginBtn.click();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

....

Comment: Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to recreate your specific error, but I was getting an error caused by invalid syntax in your subfunction.

```
        function logKey(event) {
            var l = event.keyCode;
            if(l == 13) {
                document.mainF.loginBtn.click();
            }
        });
```

should be

```
        function logKey(event) {
            var l = event.keyCode;
            if(l == 13) {
                document.mainF.loginBtn.click();
            }
        }
```

This error is present in both your sKey and logKey functions and generated a syntax error in the chrome console.

Comment: Thank you! I corrected the syntax but I am still getting a sKey is undefined when I start typing a keyword in my search section or in my logKey... Hmmmm I am wondering and spinning my wheels over this issue..

Comment: @smor Would it be possible to add a jsfiddle to your question? It would be easier to see what's possibly going wrong if I could recreate your error message.

In the mean time, because it's crying about not having keydown functions, maybe it would help to try throwing in some dummy keydown events near your keyup events.

Comment: i just noticed, your sKey function only exists after keyup event on the search box. what's happening is you're calling a nonexistent function on keydown. If you move the function outside your .keyup function, it should stop throwing that error.

Comment: @smor in addition to that, the even function is only able to pass through an inline script tag. I'm sure there's a way to use it in external files but that may take a while to get around to. For now, here's a fiddle of a working version (although you will have to do something about the keyup/keydown logic issue). https://jsfiddle.net/rd4hyd74/1/